# Custom attributes on model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to add some custom attributes to the DateTime model property generated by @Html.DisplayForModel, does MVC 4 has something build in?

Just example

I have a model class

```
public class UserViewModel
    {
        [CustomAttribute( type = "DateTime")]
        public DateTime DateStamp { get; set; }   
    }
```

Build view like this

```
@model CA.Website.Models.UserViewModel

@Html.DisplayForModel(Model)
```

and I would like to get html rendered like this

```
<div class="display-label">Date Stamp</div>
<div type="DateTime" class="display-field">1/8/2014 12:57:54 PM</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an attribute to do this, you can do it with a combination of a DisplayTemplate and the [Humanizer](https://github.com/MehdiK/Humanizer) library.

Under your `Views/Shared` folder, add a new folder called `DisplayTemplates`. Inside it, create a new partial view - I suggest you name it according to the type it will display e.g. DateTime.cshtml.

In the partial, set the `model` attribute to the type you want to display e.g.

```
@model DateTime
```

And then add the markup to show the value e.g.

```
<div class="display-label">@Html.LabelForModel()</div>
<div type="DateTime" class="display-field">@Model.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")</div>
```

To use the partial from a parent view, you just use `Html.DisplayFor`, and the MVC infrastructure does the wiring up for you between the types so that types that have a custom DisplayTemplate use it and everything else uses the default templates.

To get the `DateStamp` field label to appear as `Date Stamp`, you've got the option of using the `DisplayName` attribute (from System.ComponentModel) e.g.

```
public class UserViewModel
    [DisplayName("Date Stamp")
    public DateTime DateStamp
...
```

But a more sophisticated approach is to inspect the model you are binding against and pull the property name out of the metadata that MVC uses. This comes from the `ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName` property, which gets us `DateStamp`. We can then bring in [Humanizer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Humanizer), which has the Humanize extension method for strings which will split out PascalCased strings into separate words, giving us `Date Stamp`.

```
<div class="display-label">@Html.ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName.Humanize(LetterCasing.Title)</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `UIHint` on your model fields like this:

Model:

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    [UIHint("DateTimeField")]
    public DateTime DateStamp { get; set; }

}
```

Views/DisplayTemplates `DateTimeField.cshtml`

```
@model DateTime
<div class="display-label">Date Stamp</div>
<div type="DateTime" class="display-field">@Model.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy  HH:mm:ss tt")</div>
```

View

```
@model UserViewModel
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.DateStamp)
```

**Update**

In answer to the comment, to get it working using `@Html.DisplayForModel` change your view to this:

```
@model MvcApplication3.Controllers.HomeController.UserViewModel
@Html.DisplayForModel(Model.DateStamp)
```

And your DisplayTemplate to this:

```
@model DateTime
<div type="DateTime" class="display-field">@Model.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt")</div>
```